# Windows 10 ASUS X5D1N incompatibility

Tags: windows, keyboard, crash

Decided to upgrade my spare lappy to W10 before the deadline so reinstalled W7 from the recovery partition, installed mandatory updates and headed to the W10 update page. Apparently the lappy passed the compatibility test so several hours later W10 was installed.

Problem is every time I try to type into a dialog box the system reboots so no Notebpad, no web searching, no nothing. Also, no correct display driver so stuck with 1024x800. Mouse works so I might be able to use an on-screen keyboard if such a thing exists in order to fix things. BTW, some keyboard support works evidenced by the fact I can type in my logon password.

BTW W7 works flawlessly. Never tried W8.

Peter

Comment: Hi. Thanks for suggestion regarding possible driver issue. I've used device manager and somewhat disappointed to find that windows doesn't report anything is amiss. I looked at the support section of the ASUS site but couldn't anything remotely helpful. Anyone mamaged to get W10 working on this relic, am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a driver issue.  Sometimes Windows tries to use generic drivers for several things.  Most of the time they work.  Visit the manufacturer's site and see if they have any Win 10 drivers for your model.  If you can look under the Device Manager, you maybe able to see any devices having problems.  Look for ? or ! on devices.  Please post any errors if possible.